# Extract by <p> between h3 content nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to extract only the `<p>` that exist between Vigentes and Finalizados without achieving it.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'time'

@url = "http://www.caru.org.uy/web/servicios/llamados-a-concurso-publico-para-contratar-personal/"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
div_content = page.css('.contenido')

div_content.each do |item|

   puts item.text

   break if  item.css('h3').text == "Finalizados"

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
css = 'h3:contains(Vigentes) ~ p:has(~ h3:contains(Finalizados))'
```

But unfortunately, nokogiri doesn't behave properly for this one so we'll use xpath:

```
xpath = "//h3[contains(text(), 'Vigentes')]/following-sibling::p[./following-sibling::h3[contains(text(), 'Finalizados')]]"
page.search(xpath).each do |p|
  # do something
end
```